# Double summation taking forever to complete

Tags: summation

I am trying to compute this double summation. Here is the code...

```
fR = (1/(w*x))*((20*0.5^(-2 + w + x)*Binomial[2*(-1 + w), -1 + w]*Binomial[2*(-1 + x), -1 + x]*Boole[x < w]*
(0.5^Floor[x]*1.5^(-1 - 2*Floor[x])*Binomial[2*Floor[x], Floor[x]]*Floor[x]!*Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 1/2 + Floor[x], 2 + Floor[x], 0.8888888888888888] - 
  0.5^Floor[w + x]*1.5^(-1 - 2*Floor[w + x])*Binomial[2*Floor[w + x], Floor[w + x]]*Floor[w + x]!*Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 1/2 + Floor[w + x], 2 + Floor[w + x], 
    0.8888888888888888])^3)/1.5^(2*(-1 + w + x)))

fR = fR /. {ρ -> 0.5, n -> 5}
```

Here is the double sum...

```
NSum[NSum[w*fR, {x, 1, 100}], {w, 1, 100}]
```

Why is it taking so long to compute? I have absolutely no idea (sorry). Typically I don't run into this problem. Any code optimizations ( if possible ) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not simply using `Sum` instead? (That one finishes within 30 seconds or so for me)

Comment: No I did not. I thought *NSum* was supposed to be faster. When I numerically integrate, it's has always been recommended to me on this forum to use *NIntegrate*

Comment: I assumed it was the same for a summation. But in any event, when $n = 100000$, it still takes a long time. Ideally, I'd like to have $n=\infty$

Comment: Both Sum[Sum[w*fR, {x, 1, 200}], {w, 1, 200}]  and  Sum[Sum[w*fR, {x, 1, 300}], {w, 1, 300}] produce the same result $0.418848$ and messages about very small numbers of quantity $10^{-300}$ in several minutes.

Comment: What is the purpose of the rule application? There is no rho nor n in fR to apply it to. What/where is n?
In any case, decluttering the sum and running it for endpoints of 1000 (took about a minute) gets the same ~0.418848 as @user64494 got for the 200 and 300 endpoints.

Comment: Floor makes no sense with summation over Integers.